# .NET Email Processing Advice

Tags: c#, windows-services, automation, imap

I cant seem to find a question that is exactly or close to what im looking for so hence why i am writing  a new one.

I need some advice in regards to building a Windows Service that reads an IMAP Server for emails that have been replied to from an initial email that a system i am building sends out.

I am wondering if there is somewhere in the MIME header that i cant store say for example a RequestID from a database record in there, that i am able to reference, so i can automatically get my service to read through all the emals, and allocate the email to the Request that the email was replied from.

Does anyone have any ideas on how i can do this?

I know it is done out there in the ServiceDesk/HelpDesk Industry, just trying to work out my plan of action to get this to work correctly.

Thanks

Robbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject line is by far the most reliable field to use for a correlation ID in e-mail, as it will be included by default in replies by most e-mail clients. GUIDS can be a little non-user friendly (not to mention using up valuable space on the subject line). Because you are in control of the original message, all that matters is that you can generate a unique ID with your outgoing message.

If you have multiple senders, your unique Id can be composed of a sender identifier, the time sent, and /or a sequential id. You must be prepared to handle messages that cannot be correlated to the source through at least a manual process.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about changing the header, but its quite common to place a [GUID-STYLE-ID] in the subject of the email to track threads. I guess one could add this to the body, but it might get confusing if people copy-paste from other emails etc.

Also, I am not sure if email clients will modify and possibly replace the actual email headers?